# SWIG interface via data serialization?

Tags: java, c++, swig

I have a datatype that I'd like to use in both Java and C++:

```
MyObj foo(const MyObj& input);
std::vector<MyObj> bar(std::vector<MyObj>& input);
```

the trick is that `MyObj` is defined in a 3rd party (closed source) tool which is available to me in both Java and C++ (they've used SWIG too). My first approach was to attempt to leverage their SWIG wrappers for my purposes, but now I'm exploring a second approach which is leverage instead that I can serialize their data into a string. That is, I have these functions:

In Java:

```
String toString(MyObj mo);
MyObj fromString(String s);
```

and in C++:

```
std::string toString(const MyObj& mo);
MyObj fromString(const std::string& s);
```

Can I create a SWIG wrapper for which code that I write (outside of the SWIG file) doesn't even need to know about converting to/from strings? It would seem like it should be possible. The part I got stuck at was that this:

```
%typemap(jni) MyObj& "std::string";
%typemap(jtype) MyObj& "String";
%typemap(jstype) MyObj& "MyObj";
%typemap(javain,
   pre="String ret = toString($javainput);\n",
   pgcppname="ret")
   MyObj& "$javaclassname.getCPtr(ret)";
%template(VectorMyObj) std::vector<MyObj>;
```

was generating this error in javac:

```
./VectorMyObj.java:74: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to SWIGTYPE_p_MyObj
  exampleJNI.VectorMyObj_add(swigCPtr, this, SWIGTYPE_p_MyObj.getCPtr(ret));
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution ended up involving not assigning `%typemap(jni)` or `%typemap(jtype)` (i.e. leaving those as SWIG's default) and also writing a thin wrapper around `std::string`. SWIG provided my wrapper with a `getCPtr` I could use in my `javain` typemap.

I couldn't figure out how to get a `swigCPtr` for a Java builtin.